# angular time progress bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

According to the example on their webpage i should be able to do something like this:

```
        <timer countdown="30" interval="1000">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active {{displayProgressActive}}" style="height: 30px;"> Remaining
            time : {{countdown}} second{{secondsS}} ({{progressBar}}%). Activity? {{displayProgressActive}}
            <div class="bar" style="min-width: 2em;width: {{progressBar}}%;"></div>
        </div>
    </timer>
```

However the time is running down correctly but the progress bar is not moving. so apprently the `displayProgress` does not trigger.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: *"According to the example on their webpage.."*. You should be more specific, what directive you are using, what webpage.

Comment: Furthermore, there isn't any `displayProgress` variable in your code. And by the way, can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: You should use `ng-style` instead of `style`

Comment: yeah sorry i ment the variable progressBar

Answer (score 0):

I understood from your code that `displayProgressActive` contains a name of CSS class that you want to trigger for some condition(s), to do that in a clean way with AngularJS, use the ng-class directive like this example:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" ng-class="{'class-name': condition, 'class2-name: condition2}">....
```

So with your code you just make `ng-class="{'class-to-trigger': displayProgressActive}"`

which displayProgressActive is a boolean value that you manage from your controller

Comment: i ment the progressBar variable